# RIP Gene Wolfe, 1931–2019

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

The prolific science fiction and fantasy author Gene Wolfe is [dead at 87](https://www.tor.com/2019/04/15/gene-wolfe-in-memoriam-1931-2019/).

He is probably best known for the "dying Earth" tetralogy *The Book of the New Sun* and the rest of the Solar Cycle, but his career spanned six decades and many award-winning and award-nominated novels, novellas and short stories.

> Time itself is a thing, so it seems to me, that stands solidly like a fence of iron palings with its endless row of years; and we flow past like [the river] Gyoll, on our way to a sea from which we shall return only as rain.

Comment: I think I've only read The Fifth Head of Cerberus, which is superb. A truly "literary" piece of scifi, which to this day still puzzles me somewhat with its plot. I love it. RIP Gene Wolfe.

Comment: Dying Earth was Jack Vance. I love New Sun. RIP.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yeah I know, I tried to use it more as a genre classification

Comment: Yeah, Stormblessed's edit changed the meaning and made it wrong. I rolled back.

Comment: This is very, very saddening...